# Star-like organism seen in microscope

Tags: species-identification, microscopy, life

[image: Organism]

I found this strange star-like thing while observing a slide of onion root somatic cells. I don't know that it is; I even doubt if it is an organism. It has conical arms directed  radially outwards all over it's body. It wasn't moving. If it was indeed living,  maybe I had killed it while flaming the slide. Anyway, I am interested in knowing more about this  unexpected guest of mine. Can anyone tell me what it is ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may be a stellate trichome from a plant.

You can find other ones by taking swabs from the onion and nearby plants.

[image]

cool [images here](https://www.google.com/search?q=stellate+trichomes&source=lnms&tbm=isch)

wiki [info about trichomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichome)